# C# MongoDB Filter returns the whole object

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to create a MongoDB filter in C#.
For example i have a JSON object like this :

```
  "Username": "Tinwen",
  "Foods": [
    {
      "Fruit": "Apple",
      "Amount": 1
    },
    {
      "Fruit": "Banana",
      "Amount": 2
    },
    {
      "Fruit": "Mango",
      "Amount": 3
    },
    {
      "Fruit": "Strawberry",
      "Amount": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

And i want to create a filter that returns only the objects in the array with `Amount == 2 || Amount == 3`:

```
{
  "Username": "Tinwen",
  "Foods": [
    {
      "Fruit": "Banana",
      "Amount": 2
    },
    {
      "Fruit": "Mango",
      "Amount": 3
    },
    {
      "Fruit": "Strawberry",
      "Amount": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

I've already tried filter like this :

```
var amountFilter= Builders<MyObject>.Filter.ElemMatch(
    m => m.Foods,
    f => f.Amount == 2 || f.Amount == 3);
```

And this one :

```
var expected = new List<int>();
expected.Add(2);
expected.Add(3);
var amountFilter = Builders<MyObject>.Filter.And(Builders<MyObject>.Filter.ElemMatch(
    x => x.Foods, Builders<Foods>.Filter.And(
        Builders<Foods>.Filter.In(y => y.Amount, expected))));
```

But every time it returns me the whole object (with the full array).
For now i'm using LinQ like this:

```
List<MyObject> res = _messageCollection.Find(amountFilter).ToEnumerable().ToList();
foreach (var msg in res)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < msg.Foods.Count; j++)
   {
       if (!expected.Contains(msg.Foods[j].Amount))
       {
          msg.Foods.RemoveAt(j);
       }
   }
}
for (int i = 0; i < res.Count; i++)
{
   if (res[i].Foods.Count == 0)
   {
       res.RemoveAt(i);
   }
}
```

But I'm pretty sure it can be down using MongoDB filter (and also because it's pretty bad with LinQ). So if anyone have an answer that can help me !

Comment: You can filter the array using an Aggregation query and `$filter` array operator.

Comment: I've just tried using this ```_messageCollection.Aggregate().Match(amountFilter).ToEnumerable().ToList();```
But it still returns the whole object

Comment: Usage of the [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/). This is applied in a `$project` or `$addFields` stage. What you had tried is the `$match` stage.

Comment: I found this command but it's doesn't returns the root object only the ObjectId of the root object and the "food" element that match with the condition
```
db.getCollection('MESSAGES').aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         Foods: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$Foods",
               as: "food",
               cond: { $in: [ "$$food.Amount", [2,3] ] }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: Use the `$addFields` instead of `$project`, to include the root object.

Comment: Thanks man, it works ! I just need to find how to translate it in C# and it will be fine !

Comment: Using [MongoDB Compass - Export Pipeline to C#](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/export-pipeline-to-language/#std-label-compass-export-pipeline).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it with linq like following. but you gotta make the `Foods` property `IEnumerable<Food>`

```cs
public class User
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Food> Foods { get; set; }
}
```

the following query will do a `$filter` projection on the `Foods` array/list.

```cs
var result = await collection
    .AsQueryable()
    .Where(x => x.Foods.Any(f => f.Amount == 2 || f.Amount == 3))
    .Select(x => new User
    {
        Username = x.Username,
        Foods = x.Foods.Where(f => f.Amount == 2 || f.Amount == 3)
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: You already filtered result with 'Where'. You don't need to filter them again in 'Select'. Just write Foods = x.Foods

Comment: @AfshinM.Khiabani i suppose you haven't worked with mongodb linq before. the reason it's done twice is this. first we need to narrow down the matched records in the `Where` clause which generates a `$match` stage in mongo. the second stage is a `$project` stage in which we `$filter` out the non-matched child elements. so it is essential from a performance perspective to do the filtering twice in mongodb linq.

Comment: I worked with mango a lot. Well honestly it is NOT only for mango even in SQL after you find the records that has ANY sub records with your condition in where you need to filter out other (in this case because you don't want them). I was tired yesterday. My bad, sorry.